# Disable spell checker in Pidgin

Tags: pidgin, spell-checking

How can I disable spell checker in Pidgin? Any idea?
I searched on the web, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ON `pidgin > tools > preferences > converstions`

uncheck `Highlight Misspelled Words`

[image]

Comment: TNX. I don't know, how I missed this ... Thanks again.

Comment: If you think your question is answered, then mark it as accepted. (Click on the Tick mark present on the top left of the answer)